# acknowledgePurchase In-app billing coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am new to android and trying to implement in-app billing the first time.

I am using the google play in-app library. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

I want to implement subscription in-app purchase in kotlin.

I'm not able to resolve the issue: Suspend function 'acknowledgePurchase' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function. How can I call this function?

Here is my handlePurchase method:

```
fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        if (purchase.purchaseState === Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                val params = 
AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params.build()) }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `kotlin coroutines` in your app.

`BillingClient#acknowledgePurchase(params.build())` is a `suspended function` that should only be called from another `suspend function` or `coroutine scope`.

Let's say you are using this `fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase)` in a `fragment`, you can use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{}` to launch the same.

```
fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val result = billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params.build())
                    when (result.responseCode) {
                        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                            //success flow}
                        }
                        else -> {
                            //error flow
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```